# xslt to excel transformation without Column name in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, xlsx

This the my Excel.xsl file which i am using to convert xml to excel in asp.net. it is working fine but i don't want to show the Column name.
What should i change in this file so that column name should not be shown in my excel output?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
     xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    xmlns:user="urn:my-scripts"
     xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
    xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
    xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" > 

  <xsl:template match="/">
   <Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
    xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
    xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
    xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
    xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </Workbook>
   </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <Worksheet>
    <xsl:attribute name="ss:Name">
    <xsl:value-of select="local-name(/*/*)"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <Table x:FullColumns="1" x:FullRows="1">
      <Row>
       <xsl:for-each select="*[position() = 1]/*">
       <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">
       <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
       </Data></Cell>
     </xsl:for-each>
    </Row>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </Table>
     </Worksheet>
    </xsl:template>


   <xsl:template match="/*/*">
     <Row>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </Row>
    </xsl:template>


     <xsl:template match="/*/*/*">
     <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">
     <xsl:value-of select="."/>
     </Data></Cell>
     </xsl:template>


    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fount the solution
just comment out this code to remove heading from excel file

```
   <!--<Row>
      This code is to print the header.
       <xsl:for-each select="*[position() = 1]/*">
      <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">
      <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
      </Data></Cell>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </Row>-->
```